# form.is_valid is False but form.error isn't

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I want to submit a login. This my login view:

```
def login(request):

    context = {}
    print("ok ok ok ok ok")
    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated:
        print("ok ici")
        return render(request, "login.html")

    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        print("ok ici1")

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.POST['email']
            password = form.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            print(email)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if user.user_type == '1':
                    return render(request, "administrateur.html")
                elif user.user_type == '2':
                    return render(request, "entrepreneur.html")


        elif form.errors:
            print("errors")
            print(form.errors)
            form = AuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form

    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

and my form class for customuser in `form.py`

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=CustomUser
        fields ={'email','password'}
```

my HTML is like this

```html
<form  method="POST" action="{% url 'businessplan:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2> Vous ètes un Admin ?</h2>

    <div class="container" action >
      <input type="hidden"  name="user_type" value="1">
      <label for ="id_email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
      <input id="id_email" type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>

      <label for ="id_password" ><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
      <input id="id_password" type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit" >Login</button>
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">annuler</button>
      <span class="psw">oublier <a href="#">mot de passe?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

When I submit my `form.is_valid` returns False and 
the `form.errors` prints `(<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>User with this Email already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>)`

Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: It validates the uniqueness constraint of `username`, and thus says it can not create a `CustomUser` with that username.

Answer (score 1):

It validates the uniqueness constraint of `email`, and thus says it can not create a `CustomUser` with that username.

You can make a simple `Form`, or simply make use of the [**`AuthenticationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm). We can for example alter the [source code of the **`AuthenticationForm`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L173-L248):

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
    username/password logins.
    """
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password'}),
    )
```

In the view, we can then use the cleaned data of the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request):
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                if user.user_type == '1':
                    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
                else:
                    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: @user3828990: did you use a `forms.Form` instead of a `forms.ModelForm`?